# O(n^2*log(n)) and O(n^3) Which is bigger?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

A simple question but I am confused. 
Which one is bigger,

```
  O(n^2log(n)) or O(n^3)?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plot a graph and see

Comment: Hint: which of `n` and `log(n)` is bigger?

Comment: Which is bigger as `n` gets larger and larger, `log(n)` or `n`? (since `n^2 log(n)` is `n*n*log(n)` and `n^3` is `n*n*n`)

Comment: O(n^3) is bigger, btw.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com but I can't move it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the comments, you can always plot it on a graph or plug in very large numbers into a calculator and see where the values. `O(n)` > `O(logn)`, and as this is `O(N^2) * X`, where one `X` is `O(n)` and another is `O(logn)`, you can find out that `O(N^3)` is larger as you are multiplying.

Useful tool: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=57ad04c0f04cc92e742205985c18023e